# Finding the sums of all the solution for values of $z$ where $f(3z)=7$ in $f(\frac{x}{3})=x^2+x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem**
The problem asks us to find the values of all solution of $z$ in which it satisfies $f(3z)=7$ in the equation $f(3z)=7$ in $f(\frac{x}{3})=x^2+x+1$

**My steps**
*step 1*
I substituted $\frac{3}{x}$ into the equation to get $f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{3}{x}^2+\frac{3}{x}+1$

*but i am sure that this step wasn't correct so i went onto step 1.1:*
So then i substituted 0 into the equation to get f(0)=1
then that is where i had gotten stuck
*then because i could not go anywhere i went on to substituting x as 3 as shown in step 1.2*
through that i had gotten by substituting x as 3: 
$f(1)=13$

And this is where i really got stuck

Comment: Why not write out $f(3z)$ explicitly and solve for z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that,$$f(3z) = (9z)^2+9z+1.$$
Since $f(3z) = 7$,$$f(3z) = (9z)^2+9z+1 = 7 $$$$\Rightarrow z = -\frac{1}{3} \text{ or } \frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: I understand everything except the part when u set the second line equal to seven, can you please explain how you did that?

Comment: Sure, you said in your question that $f(3z) = 7$, since we now know an expression for $f(3z)$ -- given in the first line of my answer -- we set this to $7$ and solve for $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Well just notice that
$$f(3Z)=f\left(\frac{9Z}{3}\right)=(9Z)^2+9Z+1=7$$
Becomes the condition on $Z$. For now let $x=9Z$ giving
$$x^2+x+1=7\Rightarrow x^2+x-6=0$$
Must be satisfied. This equation has solutions
$$x=2,-3\Rightarrow 9Z=2,-3$$
Thus
$$Z=\frac{2}{9}\quad\text{or}\quad -\frac{1}{3}$$